# How to disable LWC caching on a mobile app?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, android, app, cache

So I disabled `Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance in caching` as advised to disable caching.

On my laptop, caching is disabled.

However, after making changes on my Android app I have to clear the cache using combinations of the following steps, repeatedly for **~5 or 6 times** before seeing new results:

- Settings -> Advanced -> Clear cached data
- Settings -> Advanced -> Lightning Settings -> Reload Salesforce
- App info -> Clear Cache
- App info -> Force stop

> EDIT: It seems like it updates at time intervals, rather than button
> presses.

**Currently I have to repeat this process on average 5 or 6 times** before it actually does clear the cache and reload the HTML, CSS and JavaScript. It is taking a lot of energy.
I'm looking for a simpler solution, especially for testing, *(but also for deploying new versions to users)*.

Does anyone know where to disable, or clear this caching please?

**Update 06/04/2024**

It seems that the amount of times I have to repeat these steps have been reduces to **~1 or 2 times on average** since I had set the App in which the LWC resides as start page.

Instead of launching another App on start of Salesforce, and navigating straight to the LWC page, without opening its parent App first.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to  [Clear App Cache](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386491&type=1) *Settings-->Advanced-->Clear Cached Data* on mobile app and there is no easy or better way than this.

Here is an open idea to [Clear cache option on page reload on Mobile App](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000I9xMpUAJ/clear-cache-option-on-page-reload-on-mobile-app) which you might want to review.

Also, check below options for details on clear cache.

- Chrome extension to [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=en).
- Review [Caching Problem In Salesforce Lighting Component](https://blog.truesalessoft.com/how-to-fix-the-caching-problem-in-salesforce-lighting-component/).

Comment: I would add, as much as possible, to test in a regular browser (on laptop etc), using test cases etc. Then only test on mobile when there is no other way around